# Expo + tRPC: Unable to retrieve application context. Did you forget to wrap your App inside `withTRPC` HoC?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, trpc.io

I have pretty simple tRPC server:

```
// server.ts
import { initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";
import { z } from "zod";

const t = initTRPC.create();

export const appRouter = t.router({
    greeting: t.procedure
        .input(
            z.object({
                name: z.string().optional()
            }))
        .query(({ input }) => {
            return {
                message: `hello ${input.name ?? "world"}`
            };
        }),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

And here's the client (almost vanilla `expo-template-blank-typescript`):

```
// App.tsx
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { createTRPCReact, httpBatchLink } from '@trpc/react-query';
import type { AppRouter } from '../backend';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();

const trpcClient = trpc.createClient({
  links: [
    httpBatchLink({
      url: "http://localhost:9696"
    })
  ]
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <trpc.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
          <Text>{trpc.greeting.useQuery({ name: "expo client" }).data?.message}</Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </trpc.Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And I'm getting a faily generic "Did you forget to wrap your App inside `withTRPC` HoC?" error:

[image: expo on web error]

I'm struggling to understand what went wrong here as there's `trpc.Provider` and `QueryClientProvider` already in the App's render tree and properly setup.

I'd really appreciate if I could get a hint at what's wrong with this setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but I think I found a solution.

Basically, I created another super simple `Foo.tsx` component and made tRPC calls from there, it worked perfectly.

Here's `Foo.tsx`:

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

import { trpc } from "./App";

export default function Foo() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{trpc.greeting.useQuery({ name: "expo client" }).data?.message}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

And here's the new `App.tsx` with diff markups:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { createTRPCReact, httpBatchLink } from '@trpc/react-query';
import type { AppRouter } from '../backend';

+++ import Foo from './Foo';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

--- const trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();
+++ export const trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();

const trpcClient = trpc.createClient({
  links: [
    httpBatchLink({
      url: "http://localhost:9696"
    })
  ]
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <trpc.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
---       <Text>{trpc.greeting.useQuery({ name: "expo client" }).data?.message}</Text>
+++       <Foo />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </trpc.Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```